# Why the recursive function number of nodes in a binary tree(Python) not returning correct result?

Tags: python, recursion

I am learning Python and recursion. I created a binary tree. I want to count the number of nodes and the following recursive function which accepts root node as a parameter.

```
def numberofNodes(head):
    if head==None:
        return 0
    return 1+numberofNodes(head.left)
    return 1+numberofNodes(head.right)
```

When I run the code I receive the correct output for a single node tree. For a 3 node tree I receive 2 as output, and 5 node tree, 3 as output. I saw the following code in stackoverflow which worked.

```
return 1 + numberofNodes(root.left) + umberofNodes(root.right);
```

But, I cant get the problem in my code. Please explain where I am committing the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

return exits the function and returns the element you specify. in your case only the first return is called, the second one is ignored entirely and will never be executed. Thats why the return you found on SO works, its a single return which sums the recursive function calls for right and left

Comment: Thank you. I changed to this. But it throws type error.

1+numberofNodes(head.left)

1+numberofNodes(head.right)

Comment: could you elaborate and provide more info on this? what kind of type error and in what line during which call?